# Accessing instance variables from a class with a different class

Tags: python, class, oop, variables, instance

As the title says, I need to access an instance variable from one class which is in a different file and is defined in the **init** method in that class and will be a bool. I've imported that class into another class in which I need to check if that bool is True or False before. For example if the method with which I want to check that looks like this.

```
    def remove_album(self,album_name):
        if album_name: #>>how do check to write this if?
            return 'Album has been published. It cannot be removed'
```

I need to remove 'album_name', but before I can do that I need to check that bool variable from the other imported class, which as I said is defined in the init method as self.bool=bool for example and that bool is not returned in any of the other class's methods. How do I go about that?

I don't know what to try. I know it's simple, but I just don't know how to do it yet.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. When you say you "need to access an instance variable from one class" from another class, that sounds wrong as classes should generally _encapsulate_ their data and provide a useful service to other classes that use them (that is, by providing methods that do something useful). Could you perhaps give a more complete example to explain what you mean?

Comment: If it's not a private variable, simply use the `.` notation to access the variable? e.g. `if instance.bool: ...`

Comment: The imported class let's call it Album, has a method(let's call it publish_album) which publishes that 'album' as in making the self.bool=True(it's False by default). I'm working with a class Album2, my goal is to check in that remove_album method(which is a method of class Album2) if that self.bool is True or False. Hopefully I described it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you wanted?

```
class Album:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.bool = False

    def publish_album(self):
        self.bool = True

class Album2:
    def remove_album(self, album):
        if album.bool:
            return 'Album has been published. It cannot be removed'

foo = Album()
print(foo.bool) # False
foo.publish_album() # sets foo.bool to True
print(Album2().remove_album(foo)) # Album has been published. It cannot be removed
```

Comment: But if self.bool = false it will also not removed.

Comment: @Hermann12 I'm sorry, I don't quite get what you mean. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: thanks for replay.  I think, if you have a second instance of Album, let say foo2 and self.bool = false the function remove_album should delete the instance as the function name tell us. Maybe a else … is missing.

Comment: No problem. "if you have a second instance of Album, let say foo2 and self.bool = false the function remove_album should delete the instance". Well, I'm not sure how the OP wants to implement the remove function. All I did was demonstrate the use of `.` syntax to check/access the variable of another instance. Given the OP did not elaborate how they want the function to be written, I suppose we can just leave that part as is.